# Make Icons peep out of the bottom Navigation bar

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-icons

I am using a bottom navigationbar(material) in my app, I am trying to obtain a view which looks like-[image]

It is observable that the icons are a little bit outside the boundary of the bottom bar, how to obtain this UI?
As adding padding and margin are not useful here, any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Bottom navigation - Material design](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/), this is not a ui contemplated under the original design, I think would be easier to build a new component that matches your UI instead of modifying bottom navigation view.

But if you finally manage to do it please share your solution, would be helpful for other people.

Comment: yes I used https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/ for building the bottom nav-bar but nt getting if the above-shown UI is possible  or not

Comment: I'm sure you can override some of the restrictions to end up getting this result but in my opinion would be easier to build a new component to get the result you want.

A quick solution that might work is to set a transparent background into the bottom navigation component and then add another view underneath with the white background.